# questions on getting x&y and clicking "sqrt" in graphic.py

Tags: python

I am asked to write a program that creates a calculator with graphics.py.

```
from graphics import *
from math import *
def main():
win = GraphWin('Simple Calculator',400,600)
win.setBackground('slategray')
p1 = Point(10,70)
p2 = Point(390,10)
display_box = Rectangle(p1,p2)
display_box.draw(win)
text = Text(Point(190,30),"")
text.setStyle('italic')
text.setSize(15)
text.draw(win)

p3 = Point(10,130)
p4 = Point(60,80)
plus = Rectangle(p3,p4)
plus.draw(win)
p5 = Point(35,105)
plus1 = Text(p5,"+")
plus1.setStyle('italic')
plus1.setSize(36)
plus1.draw(win)

minus = Rectangle(Point(70,130),Point(120,80))
minus.draw(win)
minus1 = Text(Point(95,105),"-")
minus1.setStyle('italic')
minus1.setSize(36)
minus1.draw(win)

times = Rectangle(Point(130,130),Point(180,80))
times.draw(win)
times1 = Text(Point(155,105),"×")
times1.setStyle('italic')
times1.setSize(36)
times1.draw(win)

divide = Rectangle(Point(190,130),Point(240,80))
divide.draw(win)
divide1 = Text(Point(215,105),"÷")
divide1.setStyle('italic')
divide1.setSize(36)
divide1.draw(win)

para1 = Rectangle(Point(250,130),Point(300,80))
para1.draw(win)
para_1 = Text(Point(275,105),"(")
para_1.setStyle('italic')
para_1.setSize(36)
para_1.draw(win)

para2 = Rectangle(Point(310,130),Point(360,80))
para2.draw(win)
para_2 = Text(Point(335,105),")")
para_2.setStyle('italic')
para_2.setSize(36)
para_2.draw(win)

x_power = Rectangle(Point(10,190),Point(60,140))
x_power.draw(win)
x_power1 = Text(Point(35,165),"^")
x_power1.setStyle('italic')
x_power1.setSize(36)
x_power1.draw(win)

sqrt = Rectangle(Point(70,190),Point(120,140))
sqrt.draw(win)
sqrt1 = Text(Point(95,165),"√ ")
sqrt1.setStyle('italic')
sqrt1.setSize(36)
sqrt1.draw(win)

sine = Rectangle(Point(130,190),Point(180,140))
sine.draw(win)
sine1 = Text(Point(155,165),"sin")
sine1.setStyle('italic')
sine1.setSize(30)
sine1.draw(win)

cosine = Rectangle(Point(190,190),Point(240,140))
cosine.draw(win)
cosine1 = Text(Point(215,165),"cos")
cosine1.setStyle('italic')
cosine1.setSize(30)
cosine1.draw(win)

tangent = Rectangle(Point(250,190),Point(300,140))
tangent.draw(win)
tangent1 = Text(Point(275,165),"tan")
tangent1.setStyle('italic')
tangent1.setSize(30)
tangent1.draw(win)

delete = Rectangle(Point(310,190),Point(360,140))
delete.draw(win)
delete1 = Text(Point(335,165),"DEL")
delete1.setStyle('italic')
delete1.setSize(25)
delete1.draw(win)

num1 = Rectangle(Point(10,270),Point(80,200))
num1.draw(win)
num1_ = Text(Point(45,235),"1")
num1_.setStyle('italic')
num1_.setSize(36)
num1_.draw(win)

num2 = Rectangle(Point(90,270),Point(160,200))
num2.draw(win)
num2_ = Text(Point(125,235),"2")
num2_.setStyle('italic')
num2_.setSize(36)
num2_.draw(win)

num3 = Rectangle(Point(170,270),Point(240,200))
num3.draw(win)
num3_ = Text(Point(205,235),"3")
num3_.setStyle('italic')
num3_.setSize(36)
num3_.draw(win)

num4 = Rectangle(Point(10,350),Point(80,280))
num4.draw(win)
num4_ = Text(Point(45,315),"4")
num4_.setStyle('italic')
num4_.setSize(36)
num4_.draw(win)

num5 = Rectangle(Point(90,350),Point(160,280))
num5.draw(win)
num5_ = Text(Point(125,315),"5")
num5_.setStyle('italic')
num5_.setSize(36)
num5_.draw(win)

num6 = Rectangle(Point(170,350),Point(240,280))
num6.draw(win)
num6_ = Text(Point(205,315),"6")
num6_.setStyle('italic')
num6_.setSize(36)
num6_.draw(win)

num7 = Rectangle(Point(10,430),Point(80,360))
num7.draw(win)
num7_ = Text(Point(45,395),"7")
num7_.setStyle('italic')
num7_.setSize(36)
num7_.draw(win)

num8 = Rectangle(Point(90,430),Point(160,360))
num8.draw(win)
num8_ = Text(Point(125,395),"8")
num8_.setStyle('italic')
num8_.setSize(36)
num8_.draw(win)

num9 = Rectangle(Point(170,430),Point(240,360))
num9.draw(win)
num9_ = Text(Point(205,395),"9")
num9_.setStyle('italic')
num9_.setSize(36)
num9_.draw(win)

num0 = Rectangle(Point(90,510),Point(160,440))
num0.draw(win)
num0_ = Text(Point(125,475),"0")
num0_.setStyle('italic')
num0_.setSize(36)
num0_.draw(win)

eq_sign = Rectangle(Point(170,510),Point(240,440))
eq_sign.draw(win)
eq = Text(Point(205,475),"=")
eq.setStyle('italic')
eq.setSize(36)
eq.draw(win)

Rectangle(Point(10,510),Point(80,440)).draw(win)
AC = Text(Point(45,475),"AC")
AC.setStyle('italic')
AC.setSize(36)
AC.draw(win)

Rectangle(Point(10,590),Point(240,520)).draw(win)
OFF = Text(Point(125,555),"OFF")
OFF.setStyle('italic')
OFF.setSize(36)
OFF.draw(win)

while True:
    px,py = Point.getX(win.getMouse()),Point.getY(win.getMouse())
    if 10<=px<=60 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"+")
    if 310<=px<=360 and 140<=py<=190:
        if len(str(text.getText())) <= 1:
            text.setText("")
        else:
            del_text = "".join(list(str(text.getText()))[:-1])
            text.setText(del_text)
    if 70<=px<=120 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"-")
    if 130<=px<=180 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"*")
    if 190<=px<=240 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"/")
    if 250<=px<=300 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"(")
    if 310<=px<=360 and 80<=py<=130:
        text.setText(text.getText()+")")
    if 90<=px<=160 and 440<=py<=510:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"0")
    if 10<=px<=80 and 200<=py<=270:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"1")
    if 90<=px<=160 and 200<=py<=270:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"2")
    if 170<=px<=240 and 200<=py<=270:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"3")
    if 10<=px<=80 and 280<=py<=350:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"4")
    if 90<=px<=160 and 280<=py<=350:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"5")
    if 170<=px<=240 and 280<=py<=350:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"6")
    if 10<=px<=80 and 360<=py<=430:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"7")
    if 90<=px<=160 and 360<=py<=430:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"8")
    if 170<=px<=240 and 360<=py<=430:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"9")
    if 170<=px<=240 and 440<=py<=510:#=
        try:
            result = eval(text.getText())
        except:
            result = "ERROR"
        text.setText(result)
    if 130<=px<=180 and 140<=py<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"sin(radians(")
    if 190<=px<=240 and 140<=py<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"cos(radians(")
    if 250<=px<=300 and 140<=py<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"tan(radians(")
    if 70<=px<=120 and 140<=py<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"sqrt(")
    if 10<=px<=60 and 140<=py<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"**(")
    if 10<=px<=80 and 440<=py<=510:#AC
        text.setText("")
    if 10<=px<=240 and 520<=py<=590:
        text.setText("One more click to exit")
        win.getMouse()
        win.close()
```

main()

why when I execute sqrt of the number , it gives error?
Another question is how to get x and y position respectively in one click as now I use two clicks to get x and y position for pressing a button

Answer (score 0):

Text doesn't define an __add__ method that lets you do a simple addition with a string. What you want is to extract the string part of that object and use that. This can be done with the method getText().

```
text.setText(text.getText()+"(")
```